# How to display a character in each string that will be replaced by the next character in the string (using BS DELETE)

Tags: c

I'm not sure how to use the delete function.
My code iterates through the string and prints out each character. I am trying to use delete for it to remove the character that was just displayed and now displays the next character in the string.

```
int main(void)
{
    char s[] = ("-\\|/");
    int i;
    int len = strlen(s);

    hConsoleOutput = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsoleOutput, PINK + WHITE_BG);

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        Sleep(500);
        printf("%c", s[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where do you use delete? Anyway, you don't need to use delete. Just backspace and then overwrite with the next character.

Comment: how would i do that? thats where im stuck on, I thought using delete might be easier but im unsure on how to use delete

Comment: I guess the obvious way would be `printf("\b%c", s[i]);` (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C#Table_of_escape_sequences)

Comment: You will probably also need to suppress stdout buffering. You could `fflush(stdout)` after the printf, or you could `setbuf(stdout, NULL);` at the beginning of your program.